# Correct way to say 'everywhere in the hotel'

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-usage

Recently I wanted to say that Wi-Fi is everywhere in a hotel. First, what came to my mind was "Wi-Fi is in the whole hotel", but it sounded very awkward to me.
My second idea was "Wi-Fi is everywhere in the hotel". I want to know whether the first way is correct and if it sounds awkward, whether the second way is correct, and lastly what is the best way to say this.

Comment: If a hotel offers wifi, it offers it everywhere. If it is not available everywhere, it probably would say so. Unless this is a case where someone has tested the entire coverage area of the wi-fi within the hotel and you're trying to convey that it's been confirmed, then "they have wi-fi" is plenty understandable I think. Coverage area _is_ wi-fi's thing.

Comment: @John they did not say anything. I had to ask.

Comment: Where were you worried the wi-fi was not?

Comment: @John There are a **lot** of hotels that offer wifi, but only in the lobby area, not in the rooms. That's very common (and annoying) practice.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, sure, and ones that have very spotty 'full' coverage. My point was only that if you don't have reason to believe otherwise, you probably don't need to qualify the coverage. Otherwise, you'd make that distinction. No biggie either way of course.

Comment: @John Having recently gone travelling around the world for half a year and booked about 25 hotels along the way, I'd have to disagree. If the hotel's site does not specifically say that wifi is available throughout the entire hotel, it is almost always safe to assume that it's only available in the lobby.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, okay. There may have been a need for the OP to make that very clear.

Comment: @John my question is about phrasing that sounds natural not about how to gain information because I got that information without problems.I just want to sound natural not ackward next time I have to ask similar question. The next question does not have to be about wifi and hotels. I am mostly concerned about conveying that something is in every part of some area.

Comment: «If it is not available everywhere, it probably would say so.»  @john no they don’t. I expect they will say “sorry about the coverage” and not update their claim.

Comment: Just for posterity, because there seems to be confusion. I was simply talking about how someone would say this normally, say, to a friend. "They've got wi-fi". Per Janus' point, if it's only available in the lobby, then _say_ "they've got wifi, but only in the lobby". If you are not speaking specifically on the hotel's behalf, then you have no knowledge of the width, breadth, spottiness, etc., of the coverage. Therefore, saying "they have wi-fi everywhere" carries the assumption that you somehow know that coverage exists at every point in the hotel. But you don't have that authority.

Comment: @Trismegistos, precisely why I'd say it as simply as possible. And in continuation of my last comment... If you are speaking on the hotel's behalf, then go ahead and advertise that benefit "There is wi-fi throughout the hotel". But if you're not, then just say "they have wi-fi", or specify where the wi-fi is restricted to. If you're just reiterating what the hotel staff told you "We have wi-fi everywhere", then the question is moot. For accuracy, you'd say it _just_ like the staff person said. Anyway, my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would offer both

- "Wifi is available throughout the hotel" (more idiomatic, as Wifi permeates/suffuses, and "throughout" is a good word to express that)

as well as

- "Wifi is all over the hotel" (a different idiomatic choice, but suggests that it is made available in (many) discrete areas of the hotel, the boundaries of which are unclear and could include "everywhere")

Answer (score 50):

A common way of saying this is:

> Wi-Fi is available throughout the hotel.

Answer (score 7):

It can be expressed in different ways...

- **"wifi available anywhere on the premises."**
- **"wifi available in all areas."**
- **"wifi signal available in every room."**
- **"wifi in all accommodations and public areas."**

Your sentences are grammatical but not idiomatic.

Comment: Question doesn't mention anything about it being free! :)

Comment: @Lemma   These are only suggestions.  If that service is charged, just omit "free".

Comment: Only the third one covers the intended meaning. 1 and 4 fail to mention where it's available. 2 suggests it is not available in the lobby and other common areas. And 5 is conceptually wrong because the rooms are part of the premises.

Comment: Also, “in premises” is unidiomatic.

Comment: I've edited and tried to improve the answer.

Answer (score 7):

if you're looking for something short, *hotel-wide wifi*.

Answer (score 2):

When I run into similar "how do I say this better" type questions, I often either change the wording or the order.  In this case, I'd change the order: "the whole hotel has Wi-Fi."

Answer (score 0):

That may work too:

> Wifi (signal) is accessible anywhere in the hotel.

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your contribution! Please provide an explanation of why this is the right answer, preferably by quoting a [reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227) such as a dictionary. This makes your post more convincing and helps explain the meaning of the suggested word or phrase. The goal of Stack Exchange is to "build a library of detailed answers" to questions. One-line answers are not as useful because without a source or explanation, it's hard to tell if the answer is really correct.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: this post does not completely answer the original poster's questions (which included "I want to know whether the first way is correct and if it sounds awkward, [and] whether the second way is correct"). Incomplete answers are OK, but adding this information would improve your post. You can add more detail to your answer by clicking on the edit link.